# How to Prove this Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality for Matrices?

Tags: matrices, inner-products, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $A$, $B$ be real $m \times n$ matrices. I want to show

$$\left\lVert A'B \right\rVert^2 \leq \left\lVert A'A \right\rVert \left\lVert B'B \right\rVert$$

where the norm is the Frobenius norm. Since $\langle A,B \rangle=Tr(AB')$ is an inner product on the space of $m \times n$ matrices Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality gives me

$$ Tr(A'A B'B) \leq \left\lVert A'A \right\rVert \left\lVert B'B \right\rVert$$

But $Tr(A'A B'B)=Tr(A B'BA')=\left\lVert A B' \right\rVert^2$ and not $\left\lVert A'B \right\rVert^2$.

It seems like only a small adjustment is needed but I can't find it!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have so far $||AB'||^2 = ||BA'||^2 \leq ||A'A|| \cdot ||B'B||$. If you relabel $A$ as $A'$ and $B$ as $B'$ you get what you want on the LHS and $||AA'|| \cdot ||BB'||$ on the RHS. But the spectrum of $AA'$ and $A'A$ is the same so $||AA'|| = ||A'A||$ and the same holds for $B$.

Comment: @pg_star Right $A'A$ and $AA'$ have the same eigenvalues! Using the spectral theorem I see that the norm of a symmetric matrix is a function of the its eigenvalues only. Thanks a lot I should have thought about this!

Comment: There is no need to deal with the eigenvalues. It suffices to note that $tr(A'AA'A)=tr(AA'AA')$ because in general we have $tr(XY)=tr(YX)$ (provided that the matrix multiplications on both sides are valid). Therefore $\|A'A\|=\|AA'\|$.

Comment: @user1551 Indeed this is a much simpler approach!